# Delphi FMX. TGrid events

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

На fmx форме лежит стандартный TGrid. В нем есть столбец типа TCheckColumn.
Грид заполняется по событиям OnGetValue, OnSetValue.
Для реагирования на вкл./откл. чекбокса щелчками мыши в строках грида к нему подключен обработчик OnSelectCell. Щелкая мышью по одной и той же ячейке в столбце грида событие OnSelectCell возникает только в момент первого нажатия мыши.
Вопрос: как реализовать генерацию события OnSelectCell даже при условии, что указатель мыши не передвигался с момента прошлого нажатия кнопок мыши ? Сейчас это событие генерируется только при смене нажатой ячейки на другую.

Живая иллюстрация всего описанного доступна на картинке с простым  примером грида из 2-колонок лежащего на форме fmx. Как видно на видео несколько раз нажимается ЛКМ и возникающие события протоколируются в окно CodeSite(на видео оно справа):
[image: Пример серии нажатий ЛКМ по ячейке грида]

Приведу тестовый пример грида на форме с подключенными обработчиками его заполнения(OnGetValue, OnSetValue) и реакции на щелчок мыши(OnCellClick). Может, кто то может показать, что нужно добавить/изменить, чтобы уверенно ловить событие нажатия ЛКМ по любой строке/ячейке в гриде при условии, что эти щелчки выполняются без смещения курсора мыши по схеме: подвел курсор(больше его не смещаем) и нажимаем мышь несколько раз. Мой опыт показывает, что событие OnCellClick работает только 1 раз в таком варианте. Дальше обязательно требуется смена фокуса с активной ячейки на другую.

```pascal
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types,
  System.UITypes,
  System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  System.Rtti,
  //
  FMX.Types,
  FMX.Controls,
  FMX.Forms,
  FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Grid.Style,
  FMX.Grid,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.ScrollBox,
  FMX.StdCtrls, 
  FMX.ImgList;
  //

type

  //строка грида
  TRow = record
    ID:integer;
    Checked:boolean;
  end;

  //Test form
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    grd: TGrid;
    CheckColumn2: TCheckColumn;
    Label2: TLabel;
    IntegerColumn1: TIntegerColumn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure grdGetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; var Value: TValue);
    procedure grdSetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; const Value: TValue);
    procedure grdCellClick(const Column: TColumn; const Row: Integer);
  private
    //контейнер значений ячеек грида
    FRowsA: array of TRow;
    FSelectedRow: integer;
    //
    procedure PopulateGrid;//заполняет Grid
    //
  end;

  //столбцы сетки
  TMyCols = (mcID, mcChecked);

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

//FormCreate
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PopulateGrid;
end;
    
{$REGION 'TGrid'}

//PopulateGrid
procedure TForm1.PopulateGrid;
const
  rows = 10;//число строк
begin
  Grd.RowCount := rows ;
  SetLength(FRowsA, rows);
  //по строкам
  for var r := 0 to rows-1 do
  begin
    //
    FRowsA[r].ID := r;           //id
    FRowsA[r].Checked := false ; //check
  end;
end;

//grdCellClick
procedure TForm1.grdCellClick(const Column: TColumn; const Row: Integer);
var
  selRow, cnt: integer;
begin
  var ci := Column.Index ;
  FSelectedRow := Row;
  cnt := grd.RowCount ;
  //колонка checked
  if ci = Ord(TMyCols.mcChecked) then
  begin
    //
    grd.RowCount := 0;
    grd.RowCount := cnt;
    grd.SelectRow(FSelectedRow);
    //
    FRowsA[Row].Checked := not FRowsA[Row].Checked;
    //
    Log.d( Format('CellClick raised: row=%d; col=%d', [Row, ci]) );
  end;
end;

//grdSetValue
procedure TForm1.grdSetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; const Value: TValue);
var
  oldVal, newVal: boolean;
begin
  //значения в ячейках сохраняет во внешний массив FRowsA
  //
  var g := Sender as TGrid;
  if not Assigned(g) then Exit;
  if (ARow < 0) or (ARow >= g.RowCount) then Exit;
  //
  //номер колонки
  case ACol of
    //колонка id
    Ord(TMyCols.mcID):
      begin
        FRowsA[ARow].Checked := Value.AsBoolean;//id
      end;
    //колонка checked
    Ord(TMyCols.mcChecked):
      begin
        oldVal := FRowsA[ARow].Checked;

        Value.TryAsType<boolean>(newVal);
        FRowsA[ARow].Checked := newVal;//checked
        Log.d( Format('OnSetValue raised: row=%d; col=%d; oldValue=%s; newValue=%s', [ARow, ACol, oldVal.ToString(), newVal.ToString()]) );
      end;
    //
  end;
  //
end;

//grdGetValue
procedure TForm1.grdGetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; var Value: TValue);
var
  val: boolean;
begin
  //значения из внешнего массива FRowsA сохраняет в ячейки сетки
  //
  var g := Sender as TGrid;
  if not Assigned(g) then Exit;
  if (ARow < 0) or (ARow >= g.RowCount) then Exit;

  //номер колонки
  case ACol of
    //колонка id
    Ord(TMyCols.mcID)  :
    begin
      Value := FRowsA[ARow].ID;
    end;
    //колонка checked
    Ord(TMyCols.mcChecked):
    begin
      Value := FRowsA[ARow].Checked;
    end;
  end;
  Log.d( Format('OnGetValue raised: row=%d; col=%d', [ARow, ACol]) );
  //
end;

{$ENDREGION}

//
end.
```

Чтобы учесть комментарий ув. teran опишу желаемое поведение грида:

1. По одинарному щелчку ЛКМ по строке требуется ее выделить и вызвать событие щелчка.
2. Если щелчок происходит повторно и без смещения курсора мыши с ячейки строки не убирать выделение строки и вызывать событие щелчка.
3. При щелчках по другим строкам хочется наблюдать выполнение условий 1) и 2)

Добавлю, что оказалось, проблема возникает с выделением строки в случае, если для запуска обновления представления грида использовать Grid.RowCount := 0; Grid.RowCount := NewCount;

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.OnCellClick

Answer (score 0):

Да, событие OnCellClick помогло. Пришлось в теле его обработчика вынудить грид выполнить цикл перерисовки путем вызова:

```
Grid.BeginUpdate;
//...
Grid.RowCount := 0;//очищаем сетку от строк
Grid.RowCount := NewCount;//новое число строк в сетке
//...
Grid.EndUpdate;
```

Comment: а при чем тут beginUpdate/rowCount и OnCellClick ? зы: beginUpdate/endUpdate в try-finally заворачивают обычно

Comment: beginUpdate/endUpdate больше для страховки и без них работает. Но без вызова Grid.RowCount := 0 и Grid.RowCount := NewCount контрол грида не выполняет цикл перерисовки, если просто вызывать Repaint. Объект Model хранящийся в свойстве TGrid реагирует на изменения в нем вызывая перерисовку контрола. Чтобы принудить модель вызвать перерисовку контрола и требуется "сброс строк". Как еще можно заставить грид вызвать OnGetValue при перерисовке я не нашел. Кто знает, пусть поделится)

Comment: у вас вопрос был про то как событие клика в грид обработать, а тут уже какие-то рассуждения про перерисовку. вот и не ясно откуда они тут взялись и зачем нужны.

Comment: Согласен с вами. Изначально вопрос был про отлов события нажатия кнопки мыши. Видимо, правильнее было описать, какое комплексное поведения я хочу получить при щелчках мышью по гриду.

Answer (score 0):

Возможное решение этой задачи:

1. Подключить обработчик события OnMouseDownClick к гриду для отлова любых нажатий и отпусканий ЛКМ по области контрола грида.
2. Подключить обработчик события OnSelectCell и в его теле выставлять флаг CanSelect := false для колонки типа TCheckColumn.
3. Для определения нажатой ячейки использовать метод грида: CellByPoint

Если эти правки внести в код в моем вопросе, то получится так:

```
    unit uMain;

    interface

    uses
      System.SysUtils,
      System.Types,
      System.UITypes,
      System.Classes,
      System.Variants,
      System.Rtti,
      //
      FMX.Types,
      FMX.Controls,
      FMX.Forms,
      FMX.Graphics,
      FMX.Dialogs,
      FMX.Grid.Style,
      FMX.Grid,
      FMX.Controls.Presentation,
      FMX.ScrollBox,
      FMX.StdCtrls, 
      FMX.ImgList;
      //

    type

     //строка грида
     TRow = record
      ID:integer;
      Checked:boolean;
     end;

     //Test form
     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       grd: TGrid;
       CheckColumn2: TCheckColumn;
       Label2: TLabel;
       IntegerColumn1: TIntegerColumn;
       procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
       procedure grdGetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; var   
       Value: TValue);
       procedure grdSetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; const 
       Value: TValue);
       procedure grdSelectCell(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; var 
       CanSelect: Boolean);
     private
       //контейнер значений ячеек грида
       FRowsA: array of TRow;
       FSelectedRow: integer;
       //
       procedure InitGrid;//заполняет Grid
       procedure Grd_OnMouseDownClick(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
       Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
       //
     end;

    //столбцы сетки
    TMyCols = (mcID, mcChecked);

    var
       Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.fmx}

    //FormCreate
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      InitGrid;
    end;
    
    {$REGION 'TGrid'}

    //PopulateGrid
    procedure TForm1.InitGrid;
    const
      rows = 10;//число строк
    begin
      Grd.RowCount := rows ;
      SetLength(FRowsA, rows);
      //по строкам
      for var r := 0 to rows-1 do
      begin
        FRowsA[r].ID := r;           //id
        FRowsA[r].Checked := false ; //check
      end;
      Grd.OnMouseDown := Grd_OnMouseDownClick;
    end;

    //grdSetValue
    procedure TForm1.grdSetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; 
    const Value: TValue);
    var
      oldVal, newVal: boolean;
    begin
      //значения в ячейках сохраняет во внешний массив FRowsA
      //
      var g := Sender as TGrid;
      if not Assigned(g) then Exit;
      if (ARow < 0) or (ARow >= g.RowCount) then Exit;
      //
      //номер колонки
      case ACol of
        //колонка id
        Ord(TMyCols.mcID):
        begin
          FRowsA[ARow].Checked := Value.AsBoolean;//id
        end;
        //колонка checked
        Ord(TMyCols.mcChecked):
        begin
          oldVal := FRowsA[ARow].Checked;

          Value.TryAsType<boolean>(newVal);
          FRowsA[ARow].Checked := newVal;//checked
          Log.d( Format('OnSetValue raised: row=%d; col=%d; oldValue=%s; 
          newValue=%s', [ARow, ACol, oldVal.ToString(), newVal.ToString()]) );
        end;
      end;
    end;

    //grdGetValue
    procedure TForm1.grdGetValue(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; 
    var Value: TValue);
    var
      val: boolean;
    begin
      //значения из внешнего массива FRowsA сохраняет в ячейки сетки
      //
      var g := Sender as TGrid;
      if not Assigned(g) then Exit;
      if (ARow < 0) or (ARow >= g.RowCount) then Exit;

      //номер колонки
      case ACol of
        //колонка id
        Ord(TMyCols.mcID)  :
        begin
          Value := FRowsA[ARow].ID;
        end;
        //колонка checked
        Ord(TMyCols.mcChecked):
        begin
          Value := FRowsA[ARow].Checked;
        end;
      end;
      Log.d( Format('OnGetValue raised: row=%d; col=%d', [ARow, ACol]) );
     //
    end;

    procedure TForm1.grdSelectCell(Sender: TObject; const ACol, ARow: Integer; 
    var CanSelect: Boolean);
    begin
      if (ACol = Ord(TMyCols.mcChecked)) then
        CanSelect := False
      else
        CanSelect := true;

     //Log.d( Format('OnSelectCell raised: row=%d; col=%d', [0, 0]) );
     CodeSite.Send( Format('OnSelectCell raised: row=%d; col=%d', [0, 0]) );
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Grd_OnMouseDownClick(Sender: TObject; Button: 
    TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    var
      r,c: integer;
      s: string;
    begin
      grd.CellByPoint(x, y, c, r);
      grd.BeginUpdate;
      //
      try
        if c = Ord(TMyCols.mcChecked) then FRowsA[r].Checked := not 
        FRowsA[r].Checked;    
        grd.SelectRow(r);
      finally
        grd.EndUpdate;
      end;
        s := FRowsA[r].Checked.ToString();
        CodeSite.Send( Format('Grd OnMouseDownClick raised: value:%s; row=%d; 
        col=%d', [s, r, c]) );
    end;

    {$ENDREGION}

    //
    end.
```